# String confusion 1) OR in if cond. and strtolower not lowering

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Trying to convert times such as - 215pm or 2:15 am or whatever to a 14:15 or 02:15 type string. (I am NOT using a TIME format for reasons to tedious to go into.)

Have managed to get an array output that contains hours, minutes and am/pm (but only if characters are present).

I want to allow erroneous characters through so I can EXPLICITLY fire an error message but a) I cannot get a "simple" OR test to work and b) `strtolower` is not working for me - I don't know why.

```
$hour= $matches['h'];
$minute=$matches['m'];

if(!array_key_exists('ap', $matches)){$matches ['ap'] ="am";};
$ampm=$matches['ap'];
strtolower ($ampm);

  debug ($hour,"hr");
  debug ($minute,"min");
  debug ($ampm,"ampm");

if ($ampm=="am" or $ampm=="pm") {echo "fine";}; // ALWAYS TRUE

if ($ampm==="am" or $ampm==="pm") {echo "fine";}; // FAILS WITH UPPER CASE AM AND PM

if ($hour<12 and $ampm=="pm") {$hour = $hour+12;};
  debug ($hour,"hr");
  debug ($minute,"min");
  debug ($ampm,"ampm");
```

So I do not understand why the simple string test `$ampm=="am" or $ampm=="pm"` is always true but that is just academic. But I REALLY do not understand why `strtolower` does not change "AM" to "am" so that I cannot even use a `===` congruence test.

Any thoughts?

Comment: PHP's string functions **RETURN** the modified string. They don't change in-place.

Comment: So obvious - thanks exhaustion setting in!

Comment: OK now I am REALLY confused. Now BOTH conditionals are working as expected. Does that mean a value returned from an array is NOT a string? I was getting a variable from `$matches['ap']` that said "am" but it would not fire the first conditional with `==`. So are variables returned from arrays not strings??? strtolower seems to have forced a string conversion or something.

Comment: `==` compares values (and will do type-coercion/conversion if need be) `===` compares types AND values. A string is a string, no matter where you store it. but `0 == '0'` is true, and `0 === '0'` is false, because the `===` version will not convert the `'0'` string to an integer.

Comment: But why was `$ampm=="am"` NOT true when `$ampm` was equal to "am" in the OR conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this to replace the variable:

```
$ampm = strtolower($ampm);
```

Also, $ampm is always true because the condition says

"if it is am, it is true OR if it is pm, it is true"

so what you want to do is:

```
if(isset($ampm) && $ampm === "am")
{
    //its am
} else if(isset($ampm) && $ampm === "pm")
{
    //its pm
} else
{
    //its neither
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (15 char min) :-)

Comment: OK but "if it is am, it is true OR if it is pm, it is true" so why is it true if it is "xx"? That is what I am testing for. I could do a NOT NOR but suspect I will hit the same problem.

Comment: You should do echo $ampm right before entering your conditional statements. It cannot be "xx" in the conditionals as in, it cannot be true. Is there some code missing? What does debug function do?

Comment: I have NO idea what happened there. I had a debug in before it and when came through it still came back `TRUE`... however... now working fine WITHOUT the `strtolower`. No idea what I did but it has gone now. Sorry for wasted time. No idea what the error could have been.

Comment: I think I may have had `if ($ampm=="am" or $ampm=="pm") echo "fine";` IE without the `{}` but i thought you could do that with a one line conditional...

Comment: 1 line conditional would be `echo ($ampm=="am" || $ampm =="pm") ? "fine" : "not fine";`

Answer (score 4):

Simple mistake in your code. Change:

```
strtolower ($ampm);
```

To:

```
$ampm = strtolower ($ampm);
```